# Is there any simulation environment provided with TDC-GP1 counter frimwaire?

Tags: simulation, eaglecad, counter, proteus, orcad

hello everybody I want to simulate an electronic circuit, I used TDC-GP1 (Time to Digital Converter) I searched in Proteus and in Pspice Cadness but didn't find this part in library, **is there any simulation environment provided with TDC-GP1 counter?**

Comment: A lot of SPICE software allows you to create your own parts and architecture for chips and define your own specifications for that chip. Have you tried that out? Alternatively, some companies may have models for you that they have created in these SPICE programs. You can probably ask them if they have a model for the software that you're utilizing. A lot of times at my job, I ask from the vendors for a model of their products for CAD or SPICE software and they do.

Comment: in fact its not clear to me how it works, so I can't create a model for it :(

Comment: maybe I have to reread the datasheet again.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about TDC-GP1, but if you need IBIS model for your TDC, you can have a look at [TDC7200 IBIS model](http://www.ti.com/lit/zip/snam176).

If you are actually looking for SPICE simulation, beware the internal structure of a TDC does not lend itself very well to SPICE simulations. The universities which did a lot of research do not seem to include the TDC in their simulations [Oulu: simulating the comparator before the TDC](http://www.ee.oulu.fi/~arik/Timing_discriminator.pdf) and [Lund: simulating the laser diode](http://www.ee.oulu.fi/~arik/Timing_discriminator.pdf).